# Lower bound on rising factorial

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to lower bound the product
$
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right),
$
where $n\ge 1$ is a natural number. Is there a better lower bound than the obvious one:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right) \ge \frac{1}{n^n}
$$
?

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an explicit formula, namely, 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac in\right)=\frac 1{n^{n-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)=\frac 1{n^{n-1}}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}j=\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This is the explicit formula based on @DavideGiraudo's result and my comment
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac in\right)=\frac 1{n^{n-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)=\frac 1{n^{n-1}}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}j=\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$